# Storing data in Riak with automatic ID?

Tags: riak

If I make a `HTTP POST` to riak, i.e `http://localhost:8098/riak/mybucket` along with JSON-encoded data `{name: "John Doe"}`, the object is saved as expected.

However, this data will be assigned to an `id` set by Riak automatically, something like `WAqRNgxZl10FK0F3FLuorByNHgN`.

Is it possible to make Riak return this `id` in the response of the `HTTP POST`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Riak documentation](http://wiki.basho.com/Basic-Riak-API-Operations.html), it returns the new key/ID in the `Location` header.

> In the output, the Location header will give the you key for that
>   object. To view the newly created object, go to
>   “http://127.0.0.1:8091/Location” in your browser.

You can see the docs [here](http://wiki.basho.com/Basic-Riak-API-Operations.html) - Scroll down to "Store a new object and assign random key "